# solrException. XML parser doesn't support XInclude option

Tags: xml, tomcat, solr, lucene, xinclude

After configuring solr4.7.2 with tomcat 7, got the error in solrAdmin page stating

SolrCore Initialization Failures

fran92:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: XML parser doesn't support XInclude option

My solr.xml file contains one core

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<solr persistent="true">
  <cores host="${host:}" adminPath="/admin/cores" hostContext="${hostContext:solr}">
    <core config="solrconfig.xml" name="fran92" instanceDir="generic" schema="schema.xml" dataDir="data"/>
</cores>
</solr>
```

and solrConfig.xml does not include any xInclude tag to include external xml.

what to do next to remove this error. ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be triggered by other configuration options than `solr.xml` and `solrconfig.xml` - the exact error message [seems to be produced by the `Currency` field](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.solr/solr-core/5.0.0/org/apache/solr/schema/CurrencyField.java/#798), which require XInclude to load its list of currencies.

While I'm not sure about the exact reason for this, my guess is that Tomcat bundles a different provider for the `javax.xml.*` classes, which doesn't support the XInclude statement. I'd try to swap it out with a recent version of Xerces or use the bundled application container for Solr (and since Solr is separating itself from the application container now,  run Solr in stand alone mode).

Comment: Thanx MatsLindh for your reply. It works after removing currency.xml from the schema.xml. Well I replaced the xerces.jar with the latest one and using Apache Solr 4.7.0 bundled jars for compilation. but still error remains same. Is there any other way to allow this option in my tomcat7. by any configuration?? Please update if found the solution.